# Not sure why my Stored Procedure isn't working between pyodbc and SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I'm pretty new to Python (2.7) and am just not a lot of help with pyodbc.  I have a script that calls a stored procedure:

```
sql = "exec gen_all.dbo.rpt_trinity_total '" + startDate + "', '"  + endDate + "'"

print sql
dbCursor.execute(sql)   
rows = dbCursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print row[0], row[1]
```

At the end of the stored procedure I returned the dates passed in, just to make sure the SP is getting called at that the parameters are getting set.  Everything looks like it should be working, but when I look at the table that is supposed to be populated by the SP, nothing is in there.  If I run the SP in Management Console, it works just fine.

I tried what was found to be the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824161/passing-parameters-to-stored-procedures-using-pyodbc), namely:

```
dbCursor.execute("{call gen_all.dbo.rpt_trinity_total(?,?)}", (startDate),(endDate))
```

but gave me the same results, nothing.
The SP itself is very simple, a TRUNCATE and INSERT, using a SELECT, based on the dates passed.

Just wonder if anyone could give some insight on this.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just tried this SP with out the insert, only the select, and it's returning just fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you did not commit on connection. `pyodbc` [disables auto-commit](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/FAQs) by default to meet Python DB API specs. Try setting `conn.autoCommit = True` or call `conn.commit()` on your connection.

Comment: The same applies to pymssql - I tried calling a stored procedure but without commit it won't make any changes. Thank you for also explaining this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

add cursors.commit() after cursors.execute(qry, params)

```
        cursors = sql_con.cursor()
        qry = "exec SP_NAME @Parm1 = ?, @Parm2 = ?"""
        params = (val1, val2)
        cursors.execute(qry, params)
        cursors.commit()
        cursors.close()
```